# change URL based on ancor tag with PHP

Tags: php, uri

I would like to be able to change different content on a page based on an anchor tag:

```
http://mydomain.com/mypage#conten1
http://mydomain.com/mypage#conten2
```

Can it be done with PHP? I've tried print_r($_GET) to see if I can get it that way, but certainly it does not work. Shall I use something like:

```
if (ereg("#content1",$REQUEST_URI)) {
   // show content 1
}
```

...or is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `print_r($_SERVER);` to see what you can work with. As powtac said, #anchors are not received by the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#` can not be accessed by a server, it is **not** transmitted by browsers to the server!

What you propably want to do is: to jump to a section on a page, you can simply do this with plain HTML:

```
<a href="#section_1">Show 1</a> 
<a href="#section_2">Show 2</a> 

<a name="section_1" /> Section 1
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<a name="section_2" /> Section 2
```

An other solution would be to catch the link via JavaScript and trigger a request to the server. This is how facebook does it.

Comment: @santa, why don't you just use GET variables? `http://mydomain.com/mypage?content1`, `http://mydomain.com/mypage?content2`. Then just check them with `if isset($_GET['content1']) {}`.

Comment: There are also great jQuery plugins, for example for tab layouts, which behave like the content is loaded from the server but is simply visually been shown. See http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs

Comment: You shouldn't use anchors without href + name is deprecated with some doctypes. Use containers with IDs, for example <div id="section_1">....</div> #section_1 will go to the top of div#content1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch content on the server-side, use ?content1 or ?content2 in URL:

```
<?php
switch (true) {
 case isset($_GET['content1'):
 // content 1 actions
 break;

 case isset($_GET['content2'):
 // content 2 actions
 break;

 default:
 // default actions
 break;
}
?>
```

Or, more classic, ?content=1 or ?content=2 in URL:

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['content']) {
 case '1':
 // content 1 actions
 break;

 case '2':
 // content 2 actions
 break;

 default:
 // default actions;
 break;
}
```

?>